# Merge to dataset according to matching dates

Tags: r, date, rows, erase

I have 2 datasets with time series.

In the dataset 1, the are 3 columns: `Date`, `price changes`, `volume`. And 1056 rows sorting by dates that start from `01-01-2005` to `31-12-2015`.

In the dataset 2, the are 3 columns: `Date`, `price changes`, `volume`. And 1028 rows sorting by dates that start from `01-01-2005` to `31-12-2015`. **But only** 1028 rows because there is missing data (i.e. missing rows).

I would like to erase in dataset 1 the rows with the dates that do not appear in dataset 2.

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
dataset1[!rownames(dataset1) %in% dataset2$Date, ]
```

The output has 1056 rows, so it does not erase anything.

Comment: are the rows of `dataset1` named with the Date ? Also, I don't get why you're negating with `!`. you probably would have more luck with `dataset1[dataset1$Date %in% dataset2$Date, ]`

Comment: You can also try `dataset1[which(dataset1$Date == dataset2$Date), ]`

Comment: Thak you very much @CathG !!!   It worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do `dataset1[dataset1$Date %in% dataset2$Date, ]`:

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- as.Date('2015-01-01') + 0:10
x <- sample(1:10, 11, replace = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(d1, x)
           d1  x
1  2015-01-01  3
2  2015-01-02  4
3  2015-01-03  6
4  2015-01-04 10
5  2015-01-05  3
6  2015-01-06  9
7  2015-01-07 10
8  2015-01-08  7
9  2015-01-09  7
10 2015-01-10  1
11 2015-01-11  3
d2 <- as.Date('2015-01-01') + seq(0, 10, 3)
y <- sample(1:10, 4)
df2 <- data.frame(d2, y)
df1[df1$d1 %in% df2$d2, ]
           d1  x
1  2015-01-01  3
4  2015-01-04 10
7  2015-01-07 10
10 2015-01-10  1
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I used @CathG's solution it was a little shorter ;)

Comment: @jonyjon, This solution is identical to CathG's solution as far as I can tell, so not sure what you mean. If this worked for you, you could also [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as a gesture of appreciation of the effort.

Comment: @David Arenburg, sorry I am a new member here. I did not know about that. but it is done now :)